# No trae imagenes en el cuerpo del correo garethp/php-ews

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de traer la informacion que se encuentra en el cuerpo del correo, incluyendo algunas imagenes que normalmente se pegan en el cuerpo del correo. Pero no me trae estas imagenes que se encuentran incrustadas en el cuerpo. Estoy usando la libreria garethp/php-ews para esto.

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use garethp\ews\API\Type;
use garethp\ews\MailAPI;

$api = MailAPI::withUsernameAndPassword('server', 'username', 'password');

$items = $api->getMailItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item instanceof Type\MessageType) {
        $emailId = $item->getItemId()->getId();
        $subject = $item->getSubject();
        echo "EmailId: " . $emailId . "<br>";
        echo "Subject: " . $subject . "<br>";
        $body = $api->getItem($item->getItemId());
        $bodyHtml = $body->getBody();
        echo "Body: " . $bodyHtml . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Con el codigo anterior me trae el cuerpo del correo, pero no las imagenes que estan incrustadas.
Asi es como las muestra en el codigo pero no trae ninguna imagen.

```
<img width="260" height="151" id="x_Imagen_x0020_1" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:image001.png@01DA1166.EB5E1980">
```

Habria alguna manera de que la traiga de una vez en base64? algo en la configuracion o de obtener esta imagen incrustada para que la muestra en otra pagina aparte del correo?